# Trying to create map with char array field invalid field error

Tags: c, linux, ebpf, bpf

I like to know how to create ebpf map with char array value

I tried like this

```
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY);
    __uint(key_size, sizeof(int));
    __uint(value_size, sizeof(char)*10);
    __uint(max_entries, 2);
} my_map SEC(".maps");
```

and this is full code for the ebpf program

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY);
    __uint(key_size, sizeof(int));
    __uint(value_size, sizeof(char)*10);
    __uint(max_entries, 2);
} my_map SEC(".maps");

SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_write")
int bpf_prog1(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    struct S {
        int pid;
        char cookie[10];
    } data;

    data.pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
//      data.cookie = 0x123;
    memcpy(data.cookie,"msg fwd",sizeof("msg fwd"));

    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &my_map, 0, &data, sizeof(data));

    return 0;


}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
int _version SEC("version") = 99;
```

and this is my user function I assigned to perf_buffer_opts

```
static void print_bpf_output(void *ctx, int cpu, void *data, __u32 size)
{
    struct {
        int pid;
        char cookie[10];
    } *e = data;
```

and this is the full code. so can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong why is saying invalid argument

```
libbpf: map 'my_map': failed to create: Invalid argument(-22)
libbpf: failed to load object './trace_output_kern.o'
ERROR: loading BPF object file failed
root@
```

full userspace code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <bpf/libbpf.h>


//create .o file root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/kern# clang -I /lib/modules/5.14.1/build -I /usr/include/bpf/ -O2 -Wall -c trace_output_user.c

static __u64 time_get_ns(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    return ts.tv_sec * 1000000000ull + ts.tv_nsec;
}

static __u64 start_time;
static __u64 cnt;

#define MAX_CNT 100000ll

static void print_bpf_output(void *ctx, int cpu, void *data, __u32 size)
{
    struct {
        int pid;
        char cookie[10];
    } *e = data;

    if (e->cookie != 0x12345678) {
        printf("BUG pid %llx cookie %s sized %d\n",
               e->pid, e->cookie, size);
        return;
    }

    cnt++;

    if (cnt == MAX_CNT) {
        printf("recv %lld events per sec\n",
               MAX_CNT * 1000000000ll / (time_get_ns() - start_time));
        return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct perf_buffer_opts pb_opts = {};
    struct bpf_link *link = NULL;
    struct bpf_program *prog;
    struct perf_buffer *pb;
    struct bpf_object *obj;
    int map_fd, ret = 0;
    char filename[256];
    FILE *f;

    //snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "..o", argv[0]);
    obj = bpf_object__open_file("./trace_output_kern.o", NULL);
    if (libbpf_get_error(obj)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: opening BPF object file failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* load BPF program */
    if (bpf_object__load(obj)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: loading BPF object file failed\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    map_fd = bpf_object__find_map_fd_by_name(obj, "my_map");
    if (map_fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: finding a map in obj file failed\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    prog = bpf_object__find_program_by_name(obj, "bpf_prog1");
    if (libbpf_get_error(prog)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: finding a prog in obj file failed\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    link = bpf_program__attach(prog);
    if (libbpf_get_error(link)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: bpf_program__attach failed\n");
        link = NULL;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    pb_opts.sample_cb = print_bpf_output;
    pb = perf_buffer__new(map_fd, 8, &pb_opts);
    ret = libbpf_get_error(pb);
    if (ret) {
        printf("failed to setup perf_buffer: %d\n", ret);
        return 1;
    }

    f = popen("taskset 1 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null", "r");
    (void) f;

    start_time = time_get_ns();
    while ((ret = perf_buffer__poll(pb, 1000)) >= 0 && cnt < MAX_CNT) {
    }
    kill(0, SIGINT);

cleanup:
    bpf_link__destroy(link);
    bpf_object__close(obj);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I don't remember for sure but I believe that perf event maps only store pointers to `struct perf_event`s, and that you may want to keep its value size at `sizeof(__u32)`. The `bpf_perf_event_output()` BPF helper and libbpf should handle the rest. (Some other map types (e.g. regular arrays) can have variable value size, but won't provide the same features as the perf array.)

Comment: @Qeole  I am trying to include linux kernel headers in  ebpf program but its keep giving me compile time error, I have include -I path/to/headers/ but still error. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key and value should be `__u32`:

```
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY);
    __uint(key_size, sizeof(__u32));
    __uint(value_size, sizeof(__u32));
} my_map SEC(".maps");
```

And you can then push your events to that map as usual:

```
bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &my_map, 0, &data, sizeof(data));
```

The `bpf_perf_event_output` helper takes the size of events as argument, so it doesn't need to be a static parameter in the map.

Comment: Does `bpf_perf_event_output` populate map with parameters of sys_write in my case. If yes then any easy way to find the exact parameters?

Comment: It's up to you to define the structure for `data` and write to the allocated object. You can define it as you wish.

Comment: The problem is I need parameters of sys_write to provide to userspace. I also recently asked question about that. Do u know how to do it?

Comment: You can use the macros `PT_REGS_PARMX` to retrieve the arguments. See examples in the Linux sources: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=PT_REGS_PARM1+path%3Asamples%2Fbpf.